# How to reference one <td> from another <td> within the same <tr> in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML table with the following structure:

```
<tr>
   <td>123</td>
   <td ondblclick="makeeditable(this);">this is some text</td>
   <td><span ondblclick="makeeditable(this);">this is some more text</span><span>flag</span></td>
</tr>
```

I am writing a JQuery snippet to make second `<td>` and the first `<span>` in the third `<td>` user-editable with a double-click (for what it's worth, the table is being generated dynamically):

```
function makeeditable(cell){
    var OriginalContent = $(cell).text();
    $(cell).html("<input id='editcell' class='input' type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
    $(cell).children().first().focus();
    $(cell).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var newContent = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().text(newContent);
        }
    });
    $(cell).children().first().blur(function(){
        $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
        $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
    });
}
```

Using the function above, I am successful in making the cells editable. However, now I need to somehow retrieve the row reference number (text inside the first `<td>`, *123* in this example) of the cell that was just edited. My question is, how can one reference the first `<td>` of a row from the context of the second `<td>` of the same row and from that of a `<span>` within yet another `<td>` of the same row?

Comment: jQuery has a siblings-function: https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: `var parent = $(cell).parent('tr');
    var first = parent.children('td')[0];
    first.innerText = "abc";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the first `TD` in the row for either the `TD` or `SPAN`, use `.closest('tr').find('td:first')`.

Here's a simplified version of your code:

```js
$('.editable ').dblclick(function() {
  var $self= $(this),
      OriginalContent = $(this).text();

  $self.closest('tr').find('td:first').text('Editing');
  
  $self
    .html('<input class="input" type="text" value="' + OriginalContent + '"/>')
    .find('input')       //the following methods now refer to the new input
    .focus()
    .keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.which === 13) {
        $self.text($(this).val());
      }
    })
    .blur(function() {
      $self.closest('tr').find('td:first').text('Double-click to edit');
    
      $self
        .text(OriginalContent)
    });
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.editable {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Double-click to edit</td>
    <td class="editable">this is some text</td>
    <td><span class="editable">this is some more text</span><span>flag</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var parent = $(cell).parent(); 
while(parent.get(0).tagName != "TR")
    parent = parent.parent();
var referenceLine = parent.children('td')[0];

// here is your reference
console.log(referenceLine.innerText);
```

Just want to add that Rick Hitchcock's answer is good and well implemented but .parent() and .children() methods are more than 3 times faster than .closest() and .find() methods : [check here and run the test](http://jsperf.com/closest-find-vs-parent-children/2).